Passing React Form Hook "register" method to a custom Typescript input component
I'm taking a React JS course with Typescript, and there's this part which shows a sign up form that uses React Form Hook. Since the course uses simple password fields, I wanted to implement a button that shows the password like on almost every modern websites, so I made a custom component for it, but I'm having issues when implementing "useForm" methods (specially "register"), as I tried a lot of ways to use it, but either it does nothing or crashes the site.
This is the password input component:
PasswordInput.tsx
import { EyeIcon, EyeSlashIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { useState } from "react";

type PasswordInputProps = {
    id: string
    customStyle: string
    placeholder: string
    className: string
}

const PasswordInput = ({ id, customStyle, placeholder, className }: PasswordInputProps) => {

    const [ showPassword, setShowPassword ] = useState(false);

    const handleToggle = () => setShowPassword(!showPassword);

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`flex relative ${customStyle}`}>
                <input
                    id={id}
                    type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    className={className}
                />
                <div className=" absolute py-2 right-1">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500"
                        onClick={handleToggle}
                    >{showPassword ? <EyeSlashIcon/> : <EyeIcon/>}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default PasswordInput;

I want to render the input inside the form like this (customStyle is for Tailwind CSS classes):
<PasswordInput
    id="password"
    customStyle="border-gray-300 border"
    placeholder="Sign up Password (min. 8 chars)"
    className="w-full px-3 py-3 "
    {...register("password", {
        required: "Password is obligatory",
        minLength: {
            value: 8,
            message: 'The password must be 8 characters minimum.'
        }
    })}
/>

I've removed the "register" props from PasswordInput.tsx for clarity, but I've tried "forwardRef", adding the "ref" inside the props and other stuff without success. There's something I may missed that doesn't let me to use it.
